# Interpreting a method with three return types in C++

Tags: c++, return

I found several lines of code in this header [FTD2XX](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Knowledgebase/index.html?ftd2xx_h.htm) that seem to have function signatures with three return types. How do I interpret this? Here is an example

```
FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_Read(
                         FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
                         LPVOID lpBuffer,
                         DWORD nBufferSize,
                         LPDWORD lpBytesReturned
);
```

All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where are the declarations of those types? They could just all be macros that amount to nothing (e.g. `#define FTD2XX_API`) or they could map to allowed keywords before functions (e.g. `__stdcall`)

Comment: No the function doesn't have "three return types", it only have one. The `WINAPI` symbol is a preprocessor macro defined in the Windows API headers. The other two symbols are probably also preprocessor macros but defined in the FTD2XX headers, and you have to find those symbols to learn what they are. My guess is that `FT_STATUS` is a macro (or a type-alias) for some type, and `FTD2XX_API` is a `declspec` compiler directive.

Comment: FTD2XX_API is given by #define FTD2XX_API __declspec(dllimport) or #define FTD2XX_API __declspec(dllexport)

Comment: `WINAPI` is a Windows thing. The other two are both defined at the top of the file, just below the explanation of `FTD2XX_API`, which says "The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting from a DLL simpler.".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual return type is just `FT_STATUS` by itself:

```
typedef ULONG   FT_STATUS;
```

`FTD2XX_API` is a macro that defines DLL import/export handling using `__declspec` directives:

```
 #ifdef FTD2XX_EXPORTS 
 #define FTD2XX_API __declspec(dllexport) 
 #else 
 #define FTD2XX_API __declspec(dllimport) 
 #endif
```

When the API is being compiled into a DLL, `FTD2XX_EXPORTS` is defined so the DLL functions are exported.  When the API is being consumed, `FTD2XX_EXPORTS` is not defined, so the DLL functions are imported.

`WINAPI` is a macro in `windef.h` that resolves to a calling convention (`__stdcall` on Windows systems):

```
#ifdef _MAC
...
#define WINAPI      CDECL
...
#elif (_MSC_VER >= 800) || defined(_STDCALL_SUPPORTED)
...
#define WINAPI      __stdcall
...
#else
...
#define WINAPI
...
#endif
```

So, your example function declaration would resolve to this (including parameter type resolutions as well):

```
__declspec(dllimport)
unsigned long  __stdcall FT_Read(
                         void *ftHandle,
                         void *lpBuffer,
                         unsigned long nBufferSize,
                         unsigned long *lpBytesReturned
);
```

These types of macros are not uncommon in APIs that are meant to be used across multiple compilers, and/or compiled into DLLs.  In this case, exported functions need to be declared differently in the implementation vs the usage, and also depending on the target platform and even the compiler used (for instance, some compilers use `extern`/`__export` instead of `__declspec(dllimport)`/`__declspec(dllexport)`).